# How can I use LINE on a second cell phone?

Tags: accounts, multiple-devices, line

Is there a way to use the same LINE account on an **additional** Android cellphone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Install e.g., the [Kiwi browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser), within which you can install the [LINE  Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc) from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/), just like on Desktop.

Sure, it's not like the full-fledged LINE app, but it's better than nothing.

[image: line extension]